# Get the Runtime Type of a Generic Type in Scala

Tags: scala, reflection

I have the following trait:

```
      trait CSVRowParser[A] {
        def parse(row: Seq[String]): Try[A]
      }

      object CSVRowParser {
        implicit def all[A, H <: HList](implicit gen: Generic.Aux[A, H],
          read: CSVRowReader[H]): CSVRowParser[A] = new CSVRowParser[A] {
          def parse(row: Seq[String]): Try[A] = {
            read.from(row).map(gen.from)
          }
        }
        def apply[A](implicit ev: CSVRowParser[A]): CSVRowParser[A] = ev
  }
```

I have another class called CSVReader:

```
class CSVReader[A: CSVRowParser] {

   def parse(path: String): ReaderWithFile[A] = ReaderWithFile[A](path)

   case class ReaderWithFile[B: CSVRowParser](path: String) {
    ...
    // how can I here identify the type of B?
   }

}
```

I then do the call like this:

```
  def apply[A: CSVRowParser] = new CSVReader[A]

  val reader = apply[Address]
  val withCustomConfig: Seq[Address] = reader parse "/csv-parser/address.csv" using CSVParserConfig(Pipe)
```

How can I get the runtime type of A inside the ReaderWithFile case class?

Comment: What you are asking for is as far as I'm able to tell a code smell. What do you want to do with the type of B? If you just want to know its name, you can use `shapeless.Typeable[T]`, why use reflection at all?

Comment: Error:(50, 38) class type required but B found
        val iden = shapeless.Typeable[B]

Comment: Spend some more time fiddling with Scala basics, it's not fun hand typing and copy pasting every single line.

```
 case class ReaderWithFile[B <: CSVRowParser : Typeable](path: String) {
   Console.println(implicitly[Typeable[B]].describe)
 }
```

Comment: That was unfortunately not so helpful. But thanks for your suggestions. I have found an alternative way to get what I want